# Core Data Versioning

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, versioning

I am having a problem trying to get a project with Core Data to do versioning.  When I try and view the version comparison pane, xcode throws an error "Document is not under source control".  If I try and view revisions, xcode throws an error "The file xxxx.xcdatamodel couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it."  I verified that I do have proper file permissions, so I am not even sure why it would even show that.  Also, I can view and edit the actual model, so it definitely is not permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what I have done wrong.  I thought versioning referred to Core Data versioning.  But it actually has to do with source control versioning.  Core Data versioning is done by going to the model editor and choosing menu item Editor -> Add Model Version...